# FindFirstFile() in Windows Kernel

Tags: windows, file, filesystems, kernel

The windows API system provides FindFirstFile() function to search files.

However, this function is not available at the kernel level.

Is there a similar function in the kernel level?

If the kernel does not have such a function, is there another way to find file by foldername?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course exist such api - [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile) and [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile). this is available in both kernel and user mode. while in user mode `Nt` and `Zw`  names point to the same function (aliases) in kernel mode - `Zw`(stub) and `Nt` (real api) - different functions.

the `FindFirstFile[Ex]` is only shell over [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile)

Comment: I was searching with the wrong keyword. Thank you for your reply!